# How to join words as below in bash

Tags: text-processing, scripting

I have a file, `words.txt` on a Linux machine, containing the following lines. How can I repeat each of the strings `user`, `apple` and `banana`, appending a number from 1 to 4 to them?

```
user
apple
banana
```

Expected Output :

```
user1
user2
user3
user4
apple1
apple2
apple3
apple4
banana1
banana2
banana3
banana4
```

I tried the following but only worked with 1 string.

```
seq 1 4 | awk {'print $0 "user"'}
```

Comment: Please show us the actual expected output. Do the `..` represent `user2` and `user3`? Are there any other strings in the original input file? Do we need to skip those?

Comment: yes they represent user2 and user3 in new line . I updated the post.

Comment: Thanks. So there are no other lines in `words.txt`? All you want is to make 4 copies of every line in the file adding a number?

Comment: yes there are no other lines in words.txt and i want to add numbers from 1 to 4 on each words in new line.

Comment: Regarding `awk {'print $0 "user"'}`, we see that once in a while and I'm extremely curious - where did you get the idea to put the `'` script delimiters inside the body of the script (i.e. inside the `{...}`) rather than outside of it `awk '{print $0 "user"}'`? Is there a book or a tutorial somewhere suggesting that's the right syntax?

Answer (score 5):

`awk` in the standard toolchest is probably your best bet here.

```
awk -v min=1 -v max=4 -v increment=1 '
  {for (i = min; i <= max; i += increment) print $0 i}' words.txt
```

With GNU tools, taking inspiration from [@JJoao's approach at taking the cartesion product of the lines of two files](/a/344315):

```
join -t $'\n' -j2 -o1.1,2.1 words.txt <(seq 4) | paste -d '\0' - -
```

Where we join `words.txt` and the output of `seq 4` on the second field, but here as we define the field delimiter as newline, there can't be a second field, or in other words, the second field is empty for every line of both files, so we end up joining everything together.

Answer (score 2):

```
sed 's/.*/&1\n&2\n&3\n&4/' words.txt
```

We are replacing (`s` command) everything on each line (`.*`), with the whole match (`&`) appearing multiple times with the literal numbers and newlines added.

Answer (score 1):

With plain bash:

```bash
while IFS= read -r word; do printf "${word}%d\\n" {1..4}; done < words.txt
```

However, putting a variable in the printf format string makes it vulnerable to unexpected characters. For example:

```bash
$ cat words.txt
with \n newline
with %s directive

$ while IFS= read -r word; do printf "${word}%d\\n" {1..4}; done < words.txt
with
 newline1
with
 newline2
with
 newline3
with
 newline4
with 1 directive2
with 3 directive4
```

Backslash sequences will be interpreted, and `%` directives will be obeyed. To protect this, the simple one-line solution becomes:

```bash
while IFS= read -r word; do
    tmp1=${word//%/%%}
    tmp2=${tmp1//\\/\\\\}
    printf "${tmp2}%d\\n" {1..4}
done < words.txt
```

which outputs

```
with \n newline1
with \n newline2
with \n newline3
with \n newline4
with %s directive1
with %s directive2
with %s directive3
with %s directive4
```

Answer (score 1):

```
% perl -nE 'chomp; for $c (1..4) { say "$_ $c"}' words.txt
```

Explanation:

- `perl -n .... words.txt` will loop over all lines in `words.txt`, setting the variable `$_` to the current line
- `-E '....'`  specifies the code to run **for each line of input**

  - `chomp` removes newline at the end of `$_`
  - `for $c (1..4)` will iterate variable $c from `1` to `4`, running the code inside `{ .... }`

    - `say "$_ $c"` will print our input line (word `user`, `apple` etc.) followed by space and counter `$c`.

so running it would result in:

```
user 1
user 2
user 3
user 4
apple 1
apple 2
apple 3
apple 4
banana 1
banana 2
banana 3
banana 4
```

Answer (score 0):

If your file really is just 4 lines long you could do something simple like:

```
$ while read word; do seq 1 4 | awk -v w="$word" '{print w$0}'; done < words.txt 
user1
user2
user3
user4
apple1
apple2
apple3
apple4
banana1
banana2
banana3
banana4
```

But [it is not a good idea](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/169716/22222) to use the shell for things like this, so here's a native GNU awk (because it keeps the original order) solution:

```
$ gawk '{ words[$0] }END{for (word in words){ for(i=1;i<5;i++){printf "%s%d\n",word,i}}}' words.txt 
user1
user2
user3
user4
apple1
apple2
apple3
apple4
banana1
banana2
banana3
banana4
```

This `awk` approach needs to read the whole file into memory. [Stéphane's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/727088/22222) is a much better solution, I recommend you use that one instead.

Comment: @alisa you're welcome! If one of the answers here solved your issue, please take a moment and [accept it](//unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) by clicking on the checkmark on the left. That is the best way to express your thanks on the Stack Exchange sites. I strongly urge you to accept Stéphane's answer because it is a much better approach.

Comment: That `words[$0]` also means that you only get unique words. `for (word in words)` loops over them in some unspecified order. Note that the behaviour of `read word` depends on the current value of `$IFS`. `read` also does some special backslash processing if you omit `-r`.

Answer (score 0):

```
for  j in $(cat file.txt); do for ((z=1;z<=4;z++)); do echo "$j$z" >>final.txt; done; done
```

output

```
user1
user2
user3
user4
apple1
apple2
apple3
apple4
banana1
banana2
banana3
banana4
```

Answer (score -2):

Pipe the file to `xargs` and use `bash` to execute your command for every word in it:

```
$ cat words.txt | xargs -I % bash -c "seq 1 4 | awk {'print \"%\"\$0'}"
user1
user2
user3
user4
apple1
apple2
apple3
apple4
banana1
banana2
banana3
banana4
```

Note that you need to escape with a backslash the double quote and dollar sign characters within the command's double quotes.